# добавить стрелки к слайдеру

Tags: javascript, html

Есть слайдер с навигацией по клику на картинки. Нужно добавить переключение слайдов по клику на стрелочки
классы стрелок - left1 right1

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function slider(item) {

    let path = item.attr('data-path');
    // let text = item.attr('value');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.demonstraition-img img').attr('src', path);
        // $('.low-energy-info').innerHTML = this.text
    }, 200);
}

$('body').on('click', '.material-img-item', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let item = $(this);

    slider(item);
});
```

});